# NullInjectorError: No provider for SlicePipe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I have created custom `pipe` which is using another build-in `pipe`
Here is example :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { SlicePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { isNumeric } from 'rxjs/util/isNumeric';

@Pipe({ name: 'range' })
export class RangePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private slicePipe: SlicePipe) { }

    transform(data: any, page: number, size: number): any {
        if (Array.isArray(data) && isNumeric(page) && isNumeric(size)) {
            const start_index = (page - 1) * size;
            if (data.length < start_index) {
                return [];
            } else {
                return this.slicePipe.transform(data.slice(start_index), size);
            }
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Also have added my custom `pipe` to `app.module`

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    routing
],
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
    RangePipe
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

But get error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[RangePipe -> SlicePipe]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RangePipe -> SlicePipe]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for SlicePipe!

Where is my problem? Do I forget to register something?

Comment: Your providers are emty. Maybe you need to put RangePipe to providers ?

Comment: @Vayrex, this doesn't help, but thx

Comment: See https://angular.io/api/core/FactoryProvider. You need to use deps:[].
Provider will provide RangePipe class, but it has SlicePipe as dependency.

Comment: @Vayrex, em, now it is working, just I need to add SlicePipe to providers instead of RangePipe. thx

Comment: You do bot fully understand how it is working =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you need to use custom class in angular DI.

```
import {FactoryProvider} from "@angular/core";
import {SlicePipe} from "@angular/common";

class AwesomePipe{
  constructor(private slicePipe: SlicePipe){

  }
}
```

and it depends on some other classes

```
class AwesomeClassProvider implements FactoryProvider{ 
  provide: AwesomePipe;
  useFactory(pipe: SlicePipe) {
    return new AwesomePipe(pipe);  
  }
  deps: [SlicePipe]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    ...
],
declarations: [
    ...
],
providers: [RangePipe],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Just extends the SlicePipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

import { SlicePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { isNumeric } from 'rxjs/util/isNumeric';

@Pipe({ name: 'range' })
export class RangePipe extends SlicePipe implements PipeTransform {
    public transform(data: any, page: number, size: number): any {
        if (Array.isArray(data) && isNumeric(page) && isNumeric(size)) {
            const start_index = (page - 1) * size;
            if (data.length < start_index) {
                return [];
            } else {
                return super.transform(data.slice(start_index), size);
            }
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help.